# Detect Accelerator Sensor for vertical changes only

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I'm new to Android's sensor, I've done a simple example that give information about phone's sensor. But I don't fully understand about these number yet: Azimuth, Pitch and Roll.

And, in case my game only requires user to rotate the phone to change the X value of object, how can I do that, so my player can play my game no matter when they are standing, sitting or lying? Any experience please?